# Adding margin between labels isn't working, Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

What I'm trying to accomplish can be found here at this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/feronezaqu/edit?html,output).
The labels need some space between the top and bottom of each other however whenever I try to add a margin like this:

```
.label-default {
    margin-bottom: 5px;      
}
```

Nothing changes, and no margin is added. How can I add a margin to make them less cluttered?

**CSS**

```
 body {
   background-color: #2d2d30;
 }
 .categories {
   padding: 25px;
   text-align: center;
   margin:auto;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
 }
 .panel-default {
   background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
   border: 0px solid;
   box-shadow: 0px;
 }
 .label-default {
   background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
   font-size: 12px;
 }
 .label-highlight {
   background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
   font-size: 12px;
 }
 .break {
   margin-top:-10px;
   display:block;
 }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="panel panel-default" style='text-align:center;max-width:960px;margin:auto;left:0;right:0;'>
   <p style='color:#fefefe;font-size:24px;font-weight:300;'>How can I add padding to the bottom of each label?</p>
   <div class="panel-body">
      <span class="label label-default pad">Default</span>
      <span class="label label-default">Primary</span>
      <span class="label label-default">Success</span>
      <span class="label label-default">Info</span>
      <span class="label label-default">Warning</span>
      <span class="label label-default">Danger</span>
      <span class="label label-default">Primary</span>
      <span class="label label-default">Success</span>
      <span class="label label-default">Info</span>
      <span class="label label-highlight">Warning</span>
      <span class="label label-default">Warning</span>
      <span class="label label-default">Danger</span>
      <span class="label label-default">Default</span>
      <span class="label label-default">Default</span>
      <span class="label label-default">Primary</span>
      <span class="label label-default">Default</span>
      <span class="label label-default">Primary</span>
      <span class="label label-default">Success</span>
      <span class="label label-default">Info</span>
       ...
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add the relevant code to your question.  If the link is down, the question is not self-sufficient and thus impossible to view, let alone answer.  Refer to our guide to creating an [mcve]

Comment: Can you check if adding this works for you? `.label{
          line-height: 25px
        }`

Answer (score 5):

Those 'labels' are `span` elements which have `display:inline`.

`margin-top` and `margin-bottom` don't work on inline elements. (see [this demo](http://codepen.io/danield770/pen/qbqVap))

To get the bottom margin to work, simply add `display: inline-block` to the label class.

```
.label-default {
   background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
   font-size: 12px;
   display: inline-block; /* <---- */
 }
```

### [Updated Jsbin](http://jsbin.com/nofofisigi/1/edit?html,output)

Answer (score 1):

Your line-height is too small for the labels.

Add this to your CSS

```
.label{ line-height: 25px }
```